# Stripe - what are all these different keys?

Tags: stripe-payments

What are all these keys and how are these used?

`Dashboard`:

- `publishable_key`
- `secret_key`
- `restricted_key`
- [`webhook_signing_secret`](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli/webhooks#listen-for-events)

The first 3 are visible in `Dashboard`.

Where are all these keys used?

---

What I've found out through trial and error: (I don't know how this would look like in production)

##### Decoding the event while CLI is running:

```
Webhook.constructEvent(rawRequestBody, signature, WEBHOOK_SIGNING_SECRET)
```

##### Setting API key globally

```
Stripe.apiKey = SECRET_KEY
```

---

My question are:

- since there is no `Stripe CLI` running in prod, is the `webhook_signing_secret` the same as the `secret_key`? (event is not forwarded through the `CLI`)
- why can't the `Stripe CLI` create an event with the signing secret encoded? it has already the `publishable_key` and `secret_key`s configured, why does it need a new one?
- where is the `restricted_key` used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Publishable keys** are used by client-side code such as Stripe.js to hit public APIs, mostly to tokenize card information.  This prevents you from being exposed to raw card info and incurring a significant [PCI compliance burden](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance).
- **Secret keys** are the API keys you use server-side to make API calls to the Stripe API.  Secret API keys must be kept secure and should be treated like a password to your account, as they can perform many critical functions like creating payments, issuing refunds, and more.
- **Restricted keys** are similar to secret keys, but they have reduced permissions that you define in the Stripe Dashboard.
- **Webhook signing secrets** are [used by your webhook endpoint code to verify the events sent to that code are actually from Stripe and not someone else pretending to be Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures).

You can read more about publishable, secret, and restricted API keys in [Stripe's documentation on API keys](https://stripe.com/docs/keys).

> since there is no `Stripe CLI` running in prod, is the `webhook_signing_secret` the same as the `secret_key`? (event is not forwarded through the `CLI`)

No, they are completely different and used for different things.

> why can't the `Stripe CLI` create an event with the signing secret encoded? it has already the `publishable_key` and `secret_keys` configured, why does it need a new one?

Including the webhook signing secret in the event would defeat the purpose, prevent the security measure from working, and not be representative of how things work in production.